# Statistical Tool to Compare Raw Data to Lower Resolution Data to Determine the Resolution When Data Is Lost

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I have dimensional data collected from a product every 1 second. The product runs can often last days and analyzing the entire dataset can be difficult due to the large amount of datapoints. The process doesn't change at time periods less than 1 second, so I'm confident I don't need that much data. There are various ways I can reduce the number of datapoints. I can collect data less frequently or I can aggregate the data by time or by length.

What statistical tool can I use to determine when I have reduced the resolution to the point that I'm losing information? I don't think a t-test or equal means test is appropriate. Would an f-test for equality of variance be appropriate? As resolution is decreased and information is degraded will variance change enough to show this? There are also tests for equivalence and distributional differences, would one of those (or another I haven't mentioned) be more appropriate?

Comment: Could you please explain what "dimensional data" are, what a "product run" is, how that might be related to "the process," what "length" means in this context, and what constitutes "information" for your purposes?

Comment: Sure. Dimensional data in this case is the thickness of plastic measured in mm. Each product is 1,000's of meters long and takes hours or day to run to end. Length is in meters and I could aggregate every 1 meter etc. Information is the dimensional data, I want to reduce the size of the dataset but still be able to capture significant deviations. The average over 100 meters for example is not very meaningful.

Comment: That helps, but we still need to know what you mean by "significant deviations."  Are you engaged in controlling the quality of this process and need to produce product within specified tolerances, for instance?  Or perhaps you want to compare product runs? Or you simply want to describe the product after it's produced?  Many more possibilities come to mind and they all have different solutions.  That's why we need to know your objectives.

Comment: Thanks for the questions. For this I'm wanting to describe the product after it is produced. Significant deviations would be out of spec. This particular dataset isn't being used to monitor the product while it is running but it can be (but is not always) used after the fact to look at product quality.

Comment: What would it cost you to continue collecting data frequently and then post-processing them into a more compact representation?  In other words, are you looking to sample less frequently or just to obtain a parsimonious description?

Comment: It is not a cost issue. Sampling is done at 1 second intervals. When I access the data I can select the interval that I would like for viewing and exporting data. It is really about efficiency in handling the data and I prefer to handle the smallest dataset possible within reason. A recent run was 62 hours, that's 223,200 datapoints for just one parameter. But if I aggregate every 1 meter for example, that's only about 10,000 datapoints. It is just much more manageable and higher resolution at some point probably does not gain me much more useful information at some point.

Comment: It's a bit in the weeds to explain, but the data collection system collects data at 1s intervals because that is how it is configured, not because we know we need datapoints every 1s. Certain people think that 1s data (which isn't the highest frequency that the equipment is capable of, but that is beside the point) is the only way to look at data. I disagree but I need to prove that. For one reason, extruders are autocorrelated so within a certain timeframe you're just seeing measurement error or noise (not including anomalous events). Also subgrouping or averaging is a common practice.

Comment: That's helpful, but it would still be useful to understand how much variation and error you can tolerate, because there are many possible solutions.

Comment: That is hard to quantify, but let's say I can tolerate a little bit of error to maybe a moderate amount of error.

Comment: Unfortunately, "little bit" and "moderate" are useless descriptions for the purpose of answering your question.

Comment: Ok. Can you give me an example of how I can better describe that?

Comment: One way would be to provide small but realistic example of what you are hoping to achieve.  Another would be to quantify what you mean by "small" and "moderate."

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help. There can't be that many tools or methods out there for what I am asking. I just wanted a list of some different ideas and then I was going to investigate which I thought would be best for my situation. What I thought was a simple question has taken up too much of my time, I am moving on to a different option that will achieve the same thing.

Comment: Asking for lists of general ideas in response to a vague inquiry certainly has value, but it doesn't work with this site.  See our [help] for more information on the kinds of questions we can address here.

Comment: To where then should I turn for help, since my question doesn't work on "this site."

Comment: You could provide the more specific information you have been asked.